# Explicit description of the smallest class of groups, that contains all finite simple groups and is closed under semidirect products

Tags: gr.group-theory, finite-groups

Suppose $\Pi$ is the smallest class of groups satisfying the following conditions:

1. All finite simple groups lie in $\Pi$
2. If $G \cong H \rtimes K$ and both $H$ and $K$ are in $\Pi$, then $G$ is also in $\Pi$

Does there exist some sort of explicit characterization of all groups lying in $\Pi$?

All I currently know, is that all groups in $\Pi$ are finite, and generalised quaternion groups are examples of finite groups not in $\Pi$. Also, finite abelian groups lie in $\Pi$ iff they are direct products of elementary abelian $p$-groups.

Comment: Why would we expect a characterisation other than the definition?